# How do I prevent Node.js / Express serving up my application's source code?

Tags: security, node.js, express

I never thought this would be a problem with Node.js and Express, but on a crazy whim I decided to type into a browser the location of one of the source files in my Node.js Express project - something like:

http://www.mywebsite.com/mynodejsapp/app.js

To my ***extreme horror***, my application's source code popped right up, publicly available for all to see.

**So, that aside: how do I stop it in Node.js / Express?**

My setup code is pretty straightforward:

```
var app = express();
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static('/home/prod/server/app/public'));
});
app.listen(8888);
```

To clarify, this is what my folder structure looks like:

`/home/prod/server/`
`/home/prod/server/app.js`
`/home/prod/server/public/`

All sorts of various files that are *intended* for public access live under `/public`. All of my server source code lives under `/server/`, and my understanding of Express's static folder configuration is that the static folder is the only place that Express happily serves up files from the filesystem from.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your app is listening on :8888 not :80 - is the url you posted correct? Are you using proxying the express app through Apache or another webserver?

Comment: Nginx proxy running on port 80, forwarding all traffic to 8888

Comment: use a static public folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what you posted it really smells like the URL you entered is served by e.g. Apache/nginx/... and you did put your node app within the document root. The answer is simple in this (and any similar) case:

You **never** put any of your sourcecode files within the document root or another HTTP-accessible folder. In your case, `/home/prod/server/app/public` should contain only client-side stuff (HTML, CSS, Graphics, (minified) client-side JS) and nginx should not have anything above this folder as its document root.

Comment: That sounds simple, but I don't think it really is; why is Express serving up anything from the filesystem *outside* of the static folder I've configured? `/home/prod/server/app/public` does only contain client-side stuff. Question clarified.

Comment: So `http://www.mywebsite.com` actually goes directly to your node webserver? I.e. no nginx/apache/whatever inbetween?

Comment: It shouldn't; my node server is running on port 8888, and I have nginx set up as a proxy to forward all port 80 traffic to 8888.

Comment: I don't have Apache installed, either.

Comment: Then it is most likely a problem with your nginx config. Try adding `root /var/empty` (or some other empty folder) to your nginx config. Also check (assuming node the request log on stdout) if those "bad" requests ever hit your node instance. I somehow doubt it.

Comment: I'll check on my nginx config.

Comment: Yep, nginx config. Insane, can't believe I let that through. Thank you.