# Openshift: how to hide server js file in a node.js app?

Tags: node.js, openshift

The server-side javascript of my app is in a file called "server.js". If anyone runs [app-name].rhcloud.com/server.js in the browser, he will be able to read all the information inside the file. So, how do we prevent this file from being public? There are some information inside it that can't just be public, like the password of the MySQL database, etc.

Comment: Keep `server.js` outside the folder where you're serving static files from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent Node.js / Express serving up my application's source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849703/how-do-i-prevent-node-js-express-serving-up-my-applications-source-code)

Comment: Sorry if it's a very simple question, but it'still not really clear to me. So basically if I create, for example, a folder called "test" and add server.js to it, then people won't be able to read it anymore? I would end with something like [app-name].rhcloud.com/test/server.js?

Comment: Commonly you might put `public` static files in a subdirectory like `app/public` which might serve up HTML, CSS, JS, or otherwise. If your application code is in `server.js`, you'd leave `server.js` in the `app` folder or something that is specifically not being served to the public. If you're not explicitly defining where static files are served from, then there is no issue unless you have a different web server like apache serving all `app` files.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: @KevinReilly , please consider posting your solution as an answer rather than as a comment.

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves Good call. I normally do and not sure why I didn't here. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 5):

Commonly you might put `public` static files in a subdirectory like `app/public` which might serve up HTML, CSS, JS, or otherwise. If your application code is in `server.js`, you'd leave `server.js` in the app folder or something that is specifically not being served to the public. If you're not explicitly defining where static files are served from, then there is no issue unless you have a different web server like apache serving all `app` files.