# Why should JSON Web Tokens (JWT) be signed with an environment variable?

Tags: json, node.js, jwt

In various tutorials I'm finding them all saying that "JWTs should be signed by an environment variable and not hard-coded into an application". From a security standpoint, if a hacker were to gain access to my Node.js application's source code, I'm assuming they could also see the environment variables on the server's system? How is it inherently more secure to call an environment variable from within Node vs. hard-coding the app's source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons for this.

1) Your signing key for the JWTs should be different for each environment (e.g. you don't want your developers knowing your production signing key). The easiest way to achieve this is to use environment variables.

2) You should abstract secret things out of the codebase. So that either means a config file or environment variable.

3) If someone does get access to your source, they at least won't have the keys to the kingdom.

4) Separation of concerns.

Comment: On point #3, how would someone gain access to source that's running on one system only, without getting access to the system itself? Is there a flaw in Node so one can read the backend code?

Comment: It's hypothetical, but yes--a flaw or misconfiguration in a front-end web server *could* allow access to source code, but not environment vars. Or, if your app does anything relating to filesystem reads and writes, you could  end up in a similar situation.

Comment: Do you have more information on security holes involving front-end misconfigurations?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, but the primary one might be serving static files using Apache / nginx but not locking down the directory docroot (or just pointing it to the wrong place by accident)

Comment: Makes sense. One of my goals is to try and make my applications as bulletproof as possible so I try to understand all of the reasons and scenarios as to why a security suggestion is made. I was more asking if there were any articles or resources that come to mind regarding situations that might expose your backend codebase by accident

Comment: No problem! Here's one SO question where the individual did exactly what I described: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849703/how-do-i-prevent-node-js-express-serving-up-my-applications-source-code

Answer (score 2):

An environment variable would only be available on the running system. Your source code however is likely in a version control repository (Github, Bitbucket, etc), on your development system, potentially in many backup locations, etc.

Essentially an environment is variable is in one place, your source code is likely in multiple.

Comment: But If I'm super careful and change the variable in my codebase before hitting "npm start", is there any theoretical security shortcoming?

Comment: Obviously for "human reasons" it's a good idea to use an environment variable in case I forget to change things, but I'm more curious if there's a technical security benefit rather than a practical one