# nodejs: allow client to use scripts but hide scripts from end-users

Tags: html, node.js, security, express, import

I have functions in my static HTML website on NodeJS in a 'functions' directory. These functions hit end-points like 'login' and get '/user' info with XMLHTTPRequest.

I dont like the idea of exposing my end-points to end-users. Is it possible to put my 'functions' directory outside of my static html directory, like:

```
 HTML
     index.html
 FUNCTIONS
     my_func.js
```

yet access my FUNCTIONS from index.html in HTML like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../FUNCTIONS/my_func.js"></script>
```

I already know this is not possible because I tried this and I just get a 404 for: www.mywebsite.com/functions/my_func.js

But really that is not the URL, because there is no URL, because I'm not wanting to host my 'functions' directory in a publicly accessible URL.

I tried this: [How do I prevent Node.js / Express serving up my application's source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849703/how-do-i-prevent-node-js-express-serving-up-my-applications-source-code)

to create a 'route' so that if 'functions' is seen in my path like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../functions/my_func.js"></script>
```

It is supposed to redirect to a directory outside of the publicly hosted HTML on nodejs, but it didnt work

I also did at the NGINX level: https://serverfault.com/questions/310124/nginx-redirect-url-containing-php

```
if ($request_uri ~ .*.functions.*) 
{
    return 410;
}
```

Which does prevent the js in the functions directory from being seen (when I put FUNCTIONS directory inside the HTML directory). However, this also prevents index.html from being able to load the js functions as well.

Comment: Why do you want to hide your API functions? If the user uses your webpage he can easily check the api endpoint calls in the network tab in various browsers, your api should be secure by itself trough tokens or sessions

Comment: paranoia i suppose. and curious if there is a better way to at least make it a little bit harder to see end-points and how they're used. Also scripts use things like sessionStorage which I know is supposed to be safe but I dont like the idea of exposing variables names if possible

Comment: i can understand you, but the user needs to connect to your api, so the browser, e.g. the end user will always see the requests made to your endpoints, even if you hide it in your javascript code etc. . I agree with @rsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your questions is: No, it's not possible.

If you host your "functions" script outside of your static directory then no one will be able to access it. If you put it somewhere when it can be accesses, then users will also be able to read it.

There is no way around it. Any code that is run by the client is possible to be read by the client. Even binary files can be disassembled so it's not only true with languages like JavaScript but also with compiled languages.

Even if people couldn't see the code itself, they would always be able to see the network traffic in their browser's developer tools where they can see all of the endpoints, parameters and data sent and received.

What you can do, though, is make sure that everyone can only do what you want them to do with those endpoints. So your endpoints should always check who is doing a request by using e.g. an authentication token and enforcing the rules of who can do what. That way people will be able to access your endpoints, but they will be able to do only the things that they can do with your frontend anyway.

Comment: Thnx for the response. How about at the NGINX proxy level if I only allowed access to the functions directory if the ip address is xyz? I guess that doesnt make sense... thoughts? (I do have oauth2 access tokens)

Comment: You can serve the functions only for people with certain ip but then people with other ip will not be able to use your app at all. Everyone who can use your app's frontend will be able to see your endpoints and the entire traffic, requests, responses, parameters, headers and everything. It's just a matter of pressing Ctrl+Shift+I.